# How to install removed apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-mate

On Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, I completely removed/uninstalled my `apt-get` because of problems I was having.

I tried re-installing it with `dpkg` by runnung:

```
 $ sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.1ubuntu2.23_amd64.deb
```

to install `apt-transport-https` then it's dependency:

```
$ sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

then I ran the two following commands

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i apt-transport-https_1.0.1ubuntu2.23_amd64.deb
```

but when I try run `apt` or `apt-get` I still get the error

> command not found

I'm still pretty new to ubuntu and I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove APT using `sudo apt remove apt`, following packages are affected in a standard installation (at least in bionic (18.04)):

```
apt apt-utils ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-desktop update-manager update-notifier update-notifier-common
```

To reinstall APT:

- Download the .deb file of APT.

  ```
  wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.10_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install using dpkg.

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.10_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install previously affected packages.

  ```
  sudo apt install apt-utils ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-desktop update-manager update-notifier update-notifier-common
  ```

***Note:*** This answer is an excerpt from [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122067/816190) on [How can I re install the APT Tool? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1122065/816190)